# Negative margin use to put label above div

Tags: html, css

I know I'm missing something basic, who wants to humble me?

What I'm shooting for;
[image]

Where I'm stuck;

```css
.labels {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  border-left: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  border-right: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  height: 10px;
}
.labels span {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#label1 {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 253px;
}
#label2 {
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="label1" class="labels">
      <span>Label 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="label2" class="labels">
      <span>Label 2</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/kkAjxQ)

Thanks, kicking the rust off after too long in the xaml world. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `span` tags are for default inline elements, therefore properties like padding or margin has no effect. You need to change that behavior:

```
.labels span {
  display:block;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

## [CodepenDemo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKkBzB)

Comment: Oh ffs, I knew it was going to be something mundane. Thanks, will accept when the time limit runs over to let me and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

add margin-top to ,labels class, and make span position fixed like the following:

```css
.labels {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  border-left: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  border-right: #9e9e9e 1px solid;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.labels span {
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: fixed;
}
#label1 {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 253px;
}
#label2 {
  width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="label1" class="labels">
      <span>Label 1</span>
   </div>
   <div id="label2" class="labels">
      <span>Label 2</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a display:block to the span!!

```
& span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I DONT recommend to use negative margins (as it may cause problems in some cases). Better way:

```css
.labels {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.labels .borders{
  border:0px solid #9e9e9e; 
  border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  height: 10px;
  width:90%;
  margin:0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="label1" class="labels">
      <span>Label 1</span>
      <span class="borders"></span>
   </div>
   <div id="label2" class="labels">
      <span>Label 2</span>
      <span class="borders"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```